Rare error in tikzpicture if i don´t use some lipsum text
I have a tikzpicture in my latex document. Additionally, I have a text from the lipsum library. The document compiles normally and the tikzpicture looks normal. For some reason, when I remove the lipsum text, a fatal error is generated and the document no longer compiles. Additionally, the error is pointed out in a line of code in the tikzpicture. I know, it's a very strange error.
I don't understand why having or not having a lipsum text would affect whether an error appears in the tikzpicture. Tikz and lipsum seem to be packages that have nothing to do with each other.
Attached I leave the latex code. If you compile it, try removing the line \lipsum[1] and you will see that a fatal error occurs.
I am using ovealeaf to compile the code. Maybe it's an overleaf error? I already tried to compile the same code in another document from another overleaf account and the error still persists.
I would greatly appreciate your help.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{apacite} 
\usepackage{bibentry} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[rmargin=2.54cm,lmargin=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\rhead{Author}
\lhead{Title}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{Institution}


\title{Title}
\author{author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\section{Some text}

\noindent Some text....

\section{Some text}

\noindent Some text....

\lipsum[1]    %   Try changing this!!!!

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %%%
    \foreach \x [count=\i from 0] in {-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} {
        \node at (\i, 2) {\x};
    }

    %%%
    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15} {
        \node[anchor=west] at (\i, 1) {(+8)}; % Ajuste a la derecha usando anchor=west
    }

    %%%
    \foreach \x [count=\i from 0] in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15} {
        \node at (\i, 0) {\x};
    }

    %%%
    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15} {
        \draw[->] (\i, 1.7) -- (\i, 0.3);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{citas}

\end{document}


Welcome! We don't have citas.bib, so we cannot compile this to reproduce the error. Can you fix this? Please also paste the text of the first error into your question.

This must be a duplicate, but finding them takes longer than answering.

Use the babel library. The error is due to the use of Babel's shorthands for Spanish.
I've commented out inputenc, which you don't need, and lipsum, which you won't want. I also had to comment out your bibliography, but that is unrelated - I just don't have your .bib file.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% do not use with non-ancient latex
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{apacite} 
\usepackage{bibentry} 
% \usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[rmargin=2.54cm,lmargin=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}% load late

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\rhead{Author}
\lhead{Title}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{Institution}


\title{Title}
\author{author}
\date{\today}

\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
  
  \maketitle
  \thispagestyle{fancy}
  
  \section{Some text}
  
  \noindent Some text....
  
  \section{Some text}
  
  \noindent Some text....
  
%   \lipsum[1]    %   Try changing this!!!!
  
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      %%%
      \foreach \x [count=\i from 0] in {-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} {
        \node at (\i, 2) {\x};
      }
      
      %%%
      \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15} {
        \node[anchor=west] at (\i, 1) {(+8)}; % Ajuste a la derecha usando anchor=west
      }
      
      %%%
      \foreach \x [count=\i from 0] in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15} {
        \node at (\i, 0) {\x};
      }
      
      %%%
      \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15} {
        \draw[->] (\i, 1.7) -- (\i, 0.3);
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  
%   \bibliographystyle{apacite}
%   \bibliography{citas}
  
\end{document}

